# Scenario to produce NTLM traffic

Tags: ntlm

I wish to perform a scenario which will produce network traffic of NTLM1 or NTLM2.

I Tried several setups but could not produce that traffic. I guess windows tries to avoid that kind of authentication these days.

Which scenario can produce NTLM traffic?
Can I use any Windows version?
Do I need to have a domain controller?
Do I need to set some policy in the policy manager of the domain controller?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not a security question but a pure Windows question.

Comment: [Microsoft NTLM (Windows)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378749(v=vs.85).aspx) "Interactive NTLM authentication over a network typically involves two systems: a client system, where the user is requesting authentication, and a domain controller, where information related to the user's password is kept. Noninteractive authentication, which may be required to permit an already logged-on user to access a resource such as a server application, typically involves three systems: a client, a server, and a domain controller"

Comment: "Do I need to have a domain controller?" Yes.

Comment: "Can I use any Windows version?" You can use any Windows version that supporst NTLM.

Comment: That's not right; all non-domain connections use NTLM (that's the only thing they can use) and very few domain connections do (most use Kerberos).

Comment: NTLM is an authentication protocol. Where do you want to see it used? HTTP authentication? SMB authentication? Something else?

Comment: @DanielB , It does not matter to me. I just want to see any scenario so that I can sniff it with wireshark.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I can use windows xp to create the scenario.
There might be other ways but I am just interested in the simplest one.

Create a lab with two windows xp machines.
Have the machines on the same network.
Have one windows xp access the other windows xp's share (see attached image) will produce ntlm traffic.

[image]